# Intentionally have the system close and restart app

Tags: android, testing

I have been seeing errors come back from my application that it's force closing after the system stop's it and the user bring it back to the front at a later time.

I have some idea's as to what is causing this but I would like to be able to reproduce this error before attempting to fix it.

Does anyone know a way to get the android system to behave like it needs the memory my application is using and close it so I can easily and continually reproduce this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Dev Tools app](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-devtools.html) on your emulator, you can have the OS destroy an application as soon as it's stopped.

From the documentation:

**Immediately destroy activities**

> Tells the system to destroy an activity as soon as it is stopped (as if Android had to reclaim memory).  This is very useful for
> testing the onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) / onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
> code path, which would otherwise be difficult to force. Choosing this
> option will probably reveal a number of problems in your application
> due to not saving state. For more information about saving an
> activity's state, see the Activities document.

You can find this under Development Settings once you're in the Dev Tools app. So, when running your application, you could just switch to another application (like clicking on the emulator's hard phone button), and return to yours to test the destroy/create process.

Comment: Awesome, did not know about the dev tools in the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse or DDMS you can select your app in the process list and hit the stop button. This should close your app.

Comment: Wow, didn't think that was going to work as I have attempted using the shell and a task manager to intentionally kill the application before, but this did the trick thanks!